# Dynamic data CONCATENATE inside ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, flatten, google-query-language

I have a (dynamic) dataset in column A, which I need to be merged individually with each of the data in column B. I have tried combining CONCATENATE/SPLIT/TRANSPOSE... with no luck = (

As far as my poor knowledge let me see, the problem would be in the way CONCATENATE works, within the ARRAYFORMULA (!?)

Any ideas on how to get the desired result in column C ??
Thank you very much... in advance!  =)

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(FILTER(A:A; A:A<>"")&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B; B:B<>"")))); "where Col1 is not null"))
```

Comment: Hi again @player0!! Thank you for your response!... You're always to the rescue! =))
I have tried, but get an ERROR: The resulting matrix is ​​too large.

Comment: @Speedbit can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U_p0U8B8JOIXGYnTn0mJnlLDugMOw2_gjH1UJD8MTn4/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the sample sheet I am testing on =)